# Web Design Process: Minifying?

Tags: html, css, minify

How does minifying codes come into place in terms of web designing?

I understand the importance of minifying in order to reduce load speed. I write my html and css codes with indentation. How I'm doing it right now is that on my local computer, I have my original codes. Then when I'm ready to upload it to a live site, I will minify it and copy/paste the code there.

So now I have 2 version of the website: original & minified.

Is this the correct way to do it, or should I write my code in the "minified" form? It'd be pretty much a mess and impossible to code if I wrote in the minified form.

Please tell me how you guys are doing it!

Comment: Write in readable form, minify by a tool upon deploy.

Comment: Minifying your source should be part of your deploy process.

If you're currently deploying by manually copying files, you really don't have a process that supports minifying. You should be deploying with a tool that can handle minification for you.

Answer (score 1):

Write your code in a clear, maintainable way. So, keep indenting, etc.

Minify your code when you deploy it. You are doing it by running a tool yourself. Many people do it as part of their build/deploy process. So you might have one command that minifies all your assets and deploys them to your server.

But if you don't have a build/deploy tool right now, then the way you're doing it is probably the way to go. Put "learning about build tools and adopting one" on your to-do/self-improvement list. You'll be glad you did.

Comment: First time I've heard about this "build tools." Can you share some helpful sites where I can learn about them? I'm a seasoned "web designer" and don't keep up-to-date with these latest tools. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

minifying is not a part of you web design process. you need to write your code nice and pretty. then use a tool to minify your css and javascript, probably as a part of your build process.

Comment: Thanks! Learned about this new "tool."

Answer (score 0):

I´m using http://gulpjs.com/ and some of its packages. It can watch my readable css (or less) and pipes it each time I save automatically through some methods like minify or prefixing (automatically adds browser specific css for older browsers which don´t support css3)

maybe check this tutorial if you want to dig deeper http://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-gulp-js/